# hdaudio codecs preventing 23.04 from booting

Tags: apt, nvidia, sound, 23.04

22.10 to 23.04 upgrade and then changing video to nVidia-525 instead of nouveau on Dell 7720 laptop.

```
Ubuntu 23.04  john-Precision-7720 tty2

John-Precision-7720 login: john
Password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 23.04 (GNU/Linux 6.2.0020-generic x86_64)

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Last login: Fri Apr 21 04:05:29 EDT 2023 on tty2
john@john-Precision-7720:~$   [33.113078]  snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[   33.113302] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[   33.114804] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b0d00. -5
[   33.114948] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b0d00. -5
```